# What timestamp format is this?

Tags: php, ssl, timestamp

Here's an easy one for someone who knows!

Here's a snippet from the returned array when querying an SSL cert for details:

```
[version] => 2
[serialNumber] => 555279728681872447526795057541980481418

   [validFrom] => 170407000000Z
   [validTo] => 180707235959Z

[validFrom_time_t] => 1491523200
[validTo_time_t] => 1531007999
[purposes] => Array...
```

Now I can see validFrom_time_t is a UNIX timestamp, but purely for interest what on earth is validFrom using?

(I was using validFrom in my script, and naturally it broke!)

PS The actual unix timestamp below it resolves to: Fri, 07 Apr 2017 00:00:00 GMT if that helps

Comment: I believe `170407000000Z` means 2017-04-07 00:00:00

Comment: I'd bet `170407000000Z` means `2017-04-07 00:00:00 Zulu (UTC)`

Comment: That sounds about right, but what format is it?

Comment: Its a date-jam as I call em. Horrible format.

Comment: @RiggsFolly a Unix **Timestamp**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding in an X.509 certificate is done with ASN.1. Timestamps are usually encoded in [ASN.1 UTCTime](https://www.obj-sys.com/asn1tutorial/node15.html) or more general in [ASN.1 GeneralizedTime](https://www.obj-sys.com/asn1tutorial/node14.html). What you see is UTCTime which means the string gets interpreted as `YYMMDDhhmmssZ`.

Comment: `openssl asn1parse` will show you both the type and content, such as: `  116:d=3  hl=2 l=  13 prim: UTCTIME           :170914000000Z`

Answer (score 1):

Steffen already did provide the gist of it. Just another resource useful: 
[A Layman's Guide to a Subset of ASN.1, BER, and DER](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html)
 which has the following:

> 5.17 UTCTime
>
> The UTCTime type denotes a "coordinated universal time" or Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) value. A UTCTime value includes the local time precise to either minutes or seconds, and an offset from GMT in hours and minutes. It takes any of the following forms:

```
YYMMDDhhmmZ
YYMMDDhhmm+hh'mm'
YYMMDDhhmm-hh'mm'
YYMMDDhhmmssZ
YYMMDDhhmmss+hh'mm'
YYMMDDhhmmss-hh'mm'
```

> where:

```
YY is the least significant two digits of the year

MM is the month (01 to 12)

DD is the day (01 to 31)

hh is the hour (00 to 23)

mm are the minutes (00 to 59)

ss are the seconds (00 to 59)

Z indicates that local time is GMT, + indicates that local time is later than GMT, and - indicates that local time is earlier than GMT

hh' is the absolute value of the offset from GMT in hours

mm' is the absolute value of the offset from GMT in minutes
```

> This type is a string type.
>
> The UTCTime type is used for signing times in PKCS #9's signing-time attribute and for certificate validity periods in X.509's Validity type.