# issue with date format with php

Tags: php, datetime

I am fetching all SSL certificate details with PHP.

In which I have got Valid date from in

> [validFrom] => 191105074645Z

format
I have tried to convert it into normal date formate with below code

```
$validFrom = date_create($certinfo['validFrom']);
echo date_format($validFrom,"Y/m/d H:i:s"); die();
echo $validFrom; die();
```

But when I print that it shows like

> 4645/05/07 00:00:00

But I want date like

> November 5, 2019

can anybody help me with this

Comment: This is in strtotime format [validFrom] => 191105074645Z?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49986180/what-timestamp-format-is-this

Comment: @04FS but how to decode that timestamp encoding exact that is my possible

Comment: The comments and answers there clearly explain that this format is `YYMMDDhhmmssZ` - so to make it into something that PHP’s strtotime parser can understand, it would be enough already to make the year portion use 4 digits instead. `date_create('20'.$certinfo['validFrom'])`

Comment: $validFrom = "191105074645Z";
$year = substr($validFrom, 0, 2);
$month = substr($validFrom, 2, 2);
$day = substr($validFrom, 4, 2);;
$hours = substr($validFrom, 6, 2);;
$minutes = substr($validFrom, 8, 2);;
$seconds = substr($validFrom, 10, 2);;
$datetime = new DateTime("$year-$month-$day $hours:$minutes:$seconds");
echo $datetime->format('F d, Y');  TRY THIS

Comment: To get the real timestamps as integer values for the validity daterange you can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-read.php#103906

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $certinfo['validFrom'] = '191105074645Z';
    $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('ymdhis',rtrim($certinfo['validFrom'], 'Z'));
    $validFrom = $date->format("F d, Y");
    var_dump($validFrom); // 'November 05, 2019'
    die();
```

simply remove Z and create date from format ;-)

EDIT : "Z" = UTC
You can force the timezone if need :

```
    $certinfo['validFrom'] = '191105074645Z';
    $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('ymdhis',rtrim($certinfo['validFrom'], 'Z'), new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $validFrom = $date->format("F d, Y"); // 'November 05, 2019'
    var_dump($validFrom); // 'November 05, 2019'
    die();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$validFrom = date_create($certinfo['validFrom']);
echo date_format($validFrom,"F d, Y"); die();
echo $validFrom; die();
```

Comment: I have already tried this but it shows the wrong result like May 07, 4645

Comment: @MNJ try my code :   $validFrom = "191105074645Z"; $year = substr($validFrom, 0, 2); $month = substr($validFrom, 2, 2); $day = substr($validFrom, 4, 2);; $hours = substr($validFrom, 6, 2);; $minutes = substr($validFrom, 8, 2);; $seconds = substr($validFrom, 10, 2);; $datetime = new DateTime("$year-$month-$day $hours:$minutes:$seconds"); echo $datetime->format('F d, Y');

Comment: @BhAvik Gajjar yes I have tried but gives me some error with substr() but when I tried the other answer it works and resolve my problem Thank you

Comment: @MNJ ok no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the date_create and with createFromFormat. Surely due to regional settings.

I used this instead of all the other proposed solutions:

```
preg_match( '/^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}).$/', $certinfo['validFrom'], $date);
array_shift($date);
[$yy, $mm, $dd, $hh, $ii, $ss] = $date;
$cert_expiry = "$mm/$dd/$yy $hh:$ii:$ss";
```